# Putting multiple statements within `for` argument

Tags: javascript

I wanted to put multiple statements in the initialization statement of a `for` loop, and I did as follows:

```
for({var i = 0; var j = 1;}; someCondition; i++){
  ...
}
```

But this seems to cause a syntax error. Isn't a single statement replacable with `{}`? Why didn't it work? Is there a way to put multiple statements in `for` argument?

Comment: The `for` initialiser is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @Bergi: Expression or variable declaration. Or I guess it's not even a variable declaration but just something with `var`. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-iteration-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{ }` to create a new block in place of a statement. But [a `for` loop requires a declaration or assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-static-semantics-early-errors).

Instead, you can use `,`.

```
for (i = 0, j = 1; someCondition: i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

> But this seems to cause a syntax error.

Yes, it does.

> Isn't a single statement replacable with {}?

No.

> Is there a way to put multiple statements in for argument?

Not really.

For this specific case you can set the value of two variables in a single expression with a comma operator.

```
for(i = 0, j = 1; someCondition; i++){
```

But it's decidedly non-idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comma to separate them. See here:

```js
for(i = 0, j = 1; i < 5; i++){
  console.log(i, j);
}
```

There's no reason to expect an expression to be replacable by an object.

Comment: I believe `{ ... }` in this case equates to a block, not an object.

Comment: @MikeC: In this case, it doesn't equate to either.

Comment: @MikeC, ah sorry, I misread it for `{i = 0, j = 1}`